# How to get inline policy document of a iam user in boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

It seems like we can get policy document of managed policy using its arn but i am not able to figure out how to get policy document of an inline policy attached to a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use IAM client.

> **get_user_policy(**kwargs)**
>
> Retrieves the specified inline policy document that is embedded in the specified IAM user.

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('iam')
response = client.get_user_policy(
    UserName='string',
    PolicyName='string'
)
```

If you want to get all inline policies attached to a user:

> **list_user_policies(**kwargs)**
>
> Lists the names of the inline policies embedded in the specified IAM user.

```
response = client.list_user_policies(
    UserName='string',
    Marker='string',
    MaxItems=123
)
```